# How to display currency symbol "AED" instead of "$" in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to show currency symbol `"AED"` instead of `"$"` with product prices. I already have changed `"Default Display Currency"` & `"Allowed Currencies"` `(United Arab Emirates Dirham)` from admin. But it is still showing `"$"` with prices instead of `"AED"`. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the system locale?

Comment: what is the relation between system locale & currency setup? I just want to show currency short form like AED instead of currency symbol like $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the displayed symbol in the section `System > Manage Currency > Symbols`.

[image: magento 1.9menu]

Answer (score 0):

1. check for `website` or `store view` configuration.
2. check the currency rates and ensure the `AED` has a value. `admin->manage currency->rates`
3. dose the value changed? if the item price is set to `1$` from catalog. look at the view is it `1$` or `3.67$` ?
4. did you cleared the cache if it's working?